# What is the name of this game?

Tags: board-games, puzzle-identification

Around 15 years ago I remember playing on my computer with this game I loved. But it turns out I never knew its name and so, I can't find it anywhere now when I want to play it again.

So, I've had to create it myself. It wasn't that hard. But still I'd love to know what it is called.

The rules are:

1. You need to shoot from the docks blocks into the center.
2. If 4 blocks of the same color touch, they are being removed.
3. The goal is to remove all blocks from the center.

Does anyone knows the name of [this game](https://shlomo666.github.io/my-board-game/)?

[image]

Comment: please upload images via imgur, through this site's interface, so that users are not required to visit unknown, potentially dangerous, sites. When editing a post, there is a way to upload images.

Comment: What are the rules of this game?

Comment: Attached image and rules.

Comment: I haven't played this before but this is a really sweet puzzle game :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks very similar to [**Brickshooter**](https://www.google.com/search?q=brickshooter&tbm=isch). I hope it helps :)

Comment: That's exactly it! Although connecting 3 instead of 4, and starting blocks not fixed etc. But that's still the same game! Thanks!